# Does the BCM43438 WiFi chip in Raspberry Pi 3 support power management setting?

Tags: wifi, pi-3

I'm trying to disable the wireless power save on my RPI3, but can't do it:

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C):
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

Is it possible, or simply not supported?

Regardless, if I don't get any problems while using the wifi card as Soft AP, is there any advantage is disabling power management?

Comment: Here is the chips technical specifications. http://www.cypress.com/file/298706/download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upgrade to "next" firmware branch:

```
sudo BRANCH=next rpi-update
```

mine is now kernel 4.4.3 and firmware 41f8b4812ad653abf321b8c54cb4bee57ebdb129 and now accepts the power off command.
My connection was constantly dropping, this appears to have sorted it!

Answer (score 17):

I'm running current kernel (4.1.19-v7+ #853), which exhibits the problem.  Updating to `BRANCH=next` didn't help, so I rolled back.

For me, although `iwconfig wlan0 power off` doesn't work, the alternative `iw dev wlan0 set power_save off` *does* work.

So I've commented-out `wireless-power off` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and replaced by:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
#   wireless-power off
    post-up iw dev $IFACE set power_save off
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

Comment: when you say sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off do you mean I open terminal and type the above words and it will not automatically shut off my wifi?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way I used that should work on any Pi- or any Debian Based distro on a Pi- to **PERSISTENTLY** disable Power Management as a ***systemd service***.

Just copy the below bash script into a file, `chmod 700` it and `sudo ./fileName` will setup a service that ensures Power Management stays down across reboots. Tested and known to work correctly on Raspbian ***Buster***:

```
if [ -d /root/scripts ]; then
    mkdir /root/scripts
fi

apt-get -y install iw
apt-get -y install wireless-tools

cat <<EOF> /root/scripts/pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.sh
#!/bin/bash
iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
EOF

chmod 700 /root/scripts/pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.sh


cat <<EOF> /etc/systemd/system//pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.service
[Unit]
Description=Disable WiFi Power Management
Requires=network-online.target
After=hostapd.service

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/scripts/pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF

chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.service

systemctl enable pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.service
systemctl start pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.service
```

Comment: `User=root` and `Group=root` is not needed, that's default. Why using a bash script? `ExecStart=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 set power_save off` will do the same job. Installing `iw` and `wireless-tools` is not needed. They are available out of the box.

Comment: Anytime I'm giving technical guidance, I avoid ambiguity like the plague.  If it's not expressly defined, a user my decide to specify the "pi" user as service owner. As for installing the tools, since `iw` is key to the solution, I expressly describe it as required.  The bash script is merely to install the service.